# Update existing attribute in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can update existing attribute and append it withot read att?

Forexample I want to add `noreferrer` in `rel` attribute.

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" rel="help noopener">FOR TEST</a>
```

target:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" rel="help noopener noreferrer">FOR TEST</a>
```

Comment: `.attr("rel", (_, oldValue) => oldValue + " noreferrer")`

Comment: @Andreas this is very good solution but if the `rel` attribute already has `noreferrer`, this is not overwrite it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery has no features for this (the traditional jQuery way is to read the attribute value then append a space and the new token before writing it back, but you rejected that). You need to go down to the native DOM API.

The [`relList` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLinkElement/relList) contains a DOMTokenList like the more commonly used `classList`.

```
const link = jQuery("selector")[0]; // Get the DOM element somehow
link.relList.add("noreferrer");
```

The documentation for [`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) points to the attributes which do support that API. It should be most of the ones where appending a value is useful. For the others, you will generally have to resort to the read then replace approach.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. If the `rel` attribute already has `noreferrer`, will it overwrite it?

Comment: "To append to an ordered set: if the set contains the given item, then do nothing; otherwise, perform the normal list append operation." — https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#set-append